# How to build a Select query (more tables without join) in ORMLite

Tags: android, sql, select, join, ormlite

What is the best way for querying this in ORMLite?

```
SELECT JOB.TASK_JOB,
            JOB.NAME_JOB,
            JOB_SETTINGS.DAY1,
            JOB_SETTINGS.DAY2,
            JOB_SETTINGS.DAY3,
            JOB_SETTINGS.DAY4,
            JOB_SETTINGS.DAY5,
            JOB_SETTINGS.DAY6,
            JOB_SETTINGS.DAY7,
            JOB_SETTINGS.HOURSPERWEEK,
            JOB_SETTINGS.PAYPERHOUR,
            JOB_SETTINGS.VARIABLEHOURS,
            WORKINGDAY.DATE_WD,
            WORKINGDAY.H_BREAK,
            WORKINGDAY.H_REAL,
            WORKINGDAY.H_IN,
            WORKINGDAY.H_OUT
        FROM JOB, JOB_SETTINGS,WORKINGDAY
        WHERE JOB.ID_JOB = JOB_SETTINGS.ID_JOB
        AND JOB_SETTINGS.ID_JOB = WORKINGDAY.ID_JOB
        AND JOB.ID_JOB = 2
```

I have a class for every tables (standard ORMLite) but I don't understand how to build this query...

Thanks!!!

**EDIT:**

I wrote this code, but actually I can't continue because I'm confused about OrmLite syntax...

```
DbHelperJob queryDao = new DbHelperJob(getActivity());

    QueryBuilder<Job, String> qJob = queryDao.getJobDao().queryBuilder();
    qJob.selectColumns("NAME_JOB", "TASK_JOB");

    QueryBuilder<JobSettings, String> qJobSett = queryDao.getJobSettDao().queryBuilder();
    qJobSett.selectColumns("DAY1", "DAY2", "DAY3", "DAY4", "DAY5", "DAY6", "DAY7", "HOURSPERWEEK", "PAYPERHOUR", "VARIABLEHOURS");

    QueryBuilder<WorkingDay, String> qWD = queryDao.getWDDao().queryBuilder();
    qWD.selectColumns("DATE_WD", "H_BREAK", "H_REAL", "H_IN", "H_OUT");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use queryRaw() method of your Dao. For example

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults = queryDao.queryRaw("SELECT JOB.TASK_JOB,
                JOB.NAME_JOB,
                JOB_SETTINGS.DAY1,
                JOB_SETTINGS.DAY2,
                JOB_SETTINGS.DAY3,
                JOB_SETTINGS.DAY4,
                JOB_SETTINGS.DAY5,
                JOB_SETTINGS.DAY6,
                JOB_SETTINGS.DAY7,
                JOB_SETTINGS.HOURSPERWEEK,
                JOB_SETTINGS.PAYPERHOUR,
                JOB_SETTINGS.VARIABLEHOURS,
                WORKINGDAY.DATE_WD,
                WORKINGDAY.H_BREAK,
                WORKINGDAY.H_REAL,
                WORKINGDAY.H_IN,
                WORKINGDAY.H_OUT
            FROM JOB, JOB_SETTINGS,WORKINGDAY
            WHERE JOB.ID_JOB = JOB_SETTINGS.ID_JOB
            AND JOB_SETTINGS.ID_JOB = WORKINGDAY.ID_JOB
            AND JOB.ID_JOB = 2")
```

read more here [enter link description here](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Raw-Queries)

Comment: It works!!! Thank you very much!! I would add +1 to answer but I don't have a minimal reputation score! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Android query have parameters:

1. **columns** - list of fields that we want to get
2. **selection** - string WHERE condition
3. **selectionArgs** - an array of arguments for
4. **selection**. In the selection, you can use the "?" And will be replaced by these values.
5. **groupBy** - grouping
6. **having** - the conditions for the use of aggregate functions
7. **orderBy** - sorting

Use it.

Comment: Yes, but in OrmLite there is a different sintax and I'm very confused about this...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ORMLite, but there's a really handy tool for doing query, right in SQLiteQueryBuilder.  You can do this:

```
private static final String COLS = new String[] {
    JOB.TASK_JOB,
    JOB.NAME_JOB,
    JOB_SETTINGS.DAY1,
    JOB_SETTINGS.DAY2,
    JOB_SETTINGS.DAY3,
    JOB_SETTINGS.DAY4,
    JOB_SETTINGS.DAY5,
    JOB_SETTINGS.DAY6,
    JOB_SETTINGS.DAY7,
    JOB_SETTINGS.HOURSPERWEEK,
    JOB_SETTINGS.PAYPERHOUR,
    JOB_SETTINGS.VARIABLEHOURS,
    WORKINGDAY.DATE_WD,
    WORKINGDAY.H_BREAK,
    WORKINGDAY.H_REAL,
    WORKINGDAY.H_IN,
    WORKINGDAY.H_OUT
}

private static String SEL =
    "JOB.ID_JOB = JOB_SETTINGS.ID_JOB"
        + "AND JOB_SETTINGS.ID_JOB = WORKINGDAY.ID_JOB"
        + "AND JOB.ID_JOB = 2"

private static String TABLES = "JOB, JOB_SETTINGS, WORKINGDAY""


// in the query method...
    db.execSQL(
        SQLiteQueryBuilder.buildQueryString(
            false, TABLES, COLS, SEL, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! But I would build this query with OrmLite...Actually, I'm writing an Android app with this library! :)
Any solutions?

Comment: Yeah.... I am pretty much anti-ORM, especially in Android.  If you really must do ORM, I think you will find the answer you need here: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#Join-Queries .  You are doing a 3-way join, which may take some tweaking... which is one of the reasons I try to avoid ORM...  Good luck